# How to remove comments/likes from a group that you left

Tags: facebook-groups

I have written comments in 2010 on photos that are in a Facebook album which belongs to a group. Then, in 2011 I left the group. Now I want to delete/remove all my comments and likes there. How can I do this? The group is an open group.